# Sources and sinks in phase space

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, phase-space

I am studying the concept of phase space in thermodynamics and there is something for which I'd like to have a physical understanding as to what it is or what it represents.

If we have sources or sinks in the phase space of an arbitrary system.

What is the physical interpretation of this? What are some observable qualities of the system, that another system, with no sinks and sources (in it's phase space) doesn't have them?

Comment: sources and sinks of what exactly?

Comment: That's the question. What do sources and sinks represent in phase space. You have a distribution function / pdf that characterizes the phase space of  system, which can be compared with the density of a fluid. Therefore concepts such as sink and source must also be present

Comment: So you are considering sources and sinks of some pdf as it evolves under a flow defined by normal time evolution? Is that correct?

Comment: yes. that is correct

Comment: I think there are no sources and sinks in the phase space

Answer (score 1):

In Statistical Mechanics, one deals with the phase space of the system. A point of the phase space corresponds to a microscopic state at a specific time of its evolution. Each microscopic state evolves according to its microscopic equations of motion and we are interested in the flux of different starting points.

A sink or a source in this dynamic evolution would imply that a macroscopic system suddenly appears or disappears or that its dynamics are suddenly activated/stopped. Something impossible.

Comment: In other words in phase space of a system : $\frac{\partial \rho(\vec q, \vec p,t)}{\partial t}+ \nabla \vec j(\vec q, \vec p,t))=0$ ?

Comment: @imbAF Yes. The absence of sinks and sources allows a continuity equation. This is the almost trivial part. Less trivial is the fact that the $\nabla \vec j $term can be written as the Poisson parenthesis of $\rho$ and the Hamiltonian. This fact has an important consequence for Statistical Mechanics: the equilibrium phase-space density must be a function of the phase point through the Hamiltonian: $\rho(\vec q, \vec p)=\rho(H(\vec q, \vec p))$.